# Setting hidden input value to a dataURL on form submit using jQuery

Tags: javascript, django, html, forms, canvas

I'm using jQuery to take take an image file from an input form, resize it in an HTML5 canvas, and convert the resized image to a dataURL. However, I can't figure out how to set the hidden input's value to the dataURL.

I've confirmed I can see the dataURL using console.log in the img.onload function, but not if I use console.log anywhere outside of the function. This is why I'm submitting the form inside img.onload. However, the value is always "Not set" when it hits the server.

```
<form id='upForm' enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr><th><label for="id_file">File:</label></th><td><input id="id_file" name="file" type="file" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='rLSVnSf35kwe9Yvq7P85lqmcp3LmC77J' />
    <BR>        
    <input type="hidden" id="myData" name="dataURL" value="Not set" />
    <input type="submit" name="sendFile" id="sendButton" value="Submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
</form>

<script>
$('#upForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var self = this;
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var dataURL = ""

    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 600, 800);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
        $('#myData').attr('value', dataURL);
        self.submit();}

    reader.onload = function(event) {
        img.src = event.target.result;}

    reader.readAsDataURL($('#id_file')[0].files[0]);

    $('#main').html('<P>Uploading receipt.<P><img src=\"/static/receipts/loading.gif\">');
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
$('#myData').attr('value', dataURL);
```

use

```
$('#myData').val(dataURL);
```